# Approach for optimizing rotation matrix, $R \in SO(3)$, with symmetric matrix of rank 2 involved.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

***Edit**: There was a mistake in my OP. I removed the PSD constraints of each $M_i$ since $\lambda_i < 0$ i.e. they are negative-semidefinite. I apologize for this change. This in turn invalidates my proposed approach of rotating $y_i$ to the null space of each $M_i$*.

---

Given

- $\{M_i\}_{i=1}^n$ as a set of $n$ 3x3 *symmetric* and negative-semidefinite matrices of *rank 2* whose eigendecomposition is $\{Q_i\,D_i\,Q_i^\top\}_{i=1}^n$, with each $D_i = \text{diag}(\lambda_i, \lambda_i, 0)$ (i.e. two repeated eigenvalues $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and one $0$-eigenvalue), and
- $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ as a set of vectors, each $\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

I'm trying to find the rotation matrix, $R\in SO(3)$, that minimizes the function $f(R)$:
$$
R = \arg\min_{R} f(R)= \arg\min_R \sum_i \left( y_i^\top R^\top M_i\, R\, y_i \right) =
\arg\min_R \sum_i \left( y_i^\top R^\top Q_i\, D_i\, Q_i^\top R\, y_i \right).
$$

*(The following is wrong, see **edit** above)* Since one eigenvalue of each $M_i$ is $0$, and, by letting $q_{0i}$ denote its associated eigenvector, I thought of simplifying the previous problem to:
$$
R = \arg\max_{R} \sum_i \left( q_{0i}^\top R\, y_i \right),
$$
Thus, aiming at the rotation that rotates the data vectors $y_i$ to the null space of each $M_i$. This new problem is similar to the [Wahba's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem) and hence can be solved in closed-form.

However (I may be ignoring some other details), I noted that this simplification suffers from the *sign ambiguity* of the eigenvectors $q_{0i}$. This is the reason why I currently think that this solution does not work in my original problem.

Given this observation, is there a way of choosing the right sign / orientation of each $q_{0i}$?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unless your $D_i$ has two repeated eigenvalues (i.e., unless $D_i$ is a scalar multiple of the orthogonal projection $I-q_{0i}q_{0i}^T$, I don't see how you can convert the minimisation problem into your maximisation problem. And even if this conversion is valid, you seem to be missing a square power in your function to maximise.

Comment: @user1551 thank you for your help. Yes, in my problem each $D_i$ has two real and repeated eigenvalues and one $0$-eigenvalue. I have updated the OP adding this. Concretely, each matrix $$M_i = -\text{skew}(x_i)^\top \text{skew}(x_i),$$ with $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\text{skew}(x_i)$ being its skew-symmetric matrix representation.